# Dynamically read the columns of the :NEW object in an oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have an oracle trigger that needs to copy values from the updated table to another table.

The problem is that the columns aren't known when the trigger is created.  Part of this system allows the table schema to be updated by the application. (don't ask).

Essentially what I want to do is pivot the table to another table.

I have a stored procedure that will do the pivot, but I can't call it as part of the trigger because it does a select on the table being updated. Causing a "mutating" error.

What would be ideal would be to create a dynamic scripts that reads all the column names from `user_tab_cols` for the updated table, and reads the value from the `:new` object.

But of course...I can't :)

`:NEW` doesn't exist at the point the dynamic script is executed.  So something like the following would fail:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE `insert into pivotTable values(:NEW.' || variableWithColumnName ||')';
```

So, I'm stuck.

I can't read from the table that was updated, and I can't read the value that was updated from the `:NEW` object.

Is there anyway to accomplish this other than rebuilding the trigger each time the schema is changed?

Comment: You could use Oracle Streams and capture LCRs (logical change records), but that is a lot of work and overhead.

Comment: I'm leaning towards rebuilding the triggers, it seems like this is much more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You'll need to rebuild the trigger whenever the table changes.

If you want to get really involved, you could write a procedure that dynamically generated the DDL to `CREATE OR REPLACE` the trigger by reading `user_tab_columns`.  You could then create a DDL trigger that fired when the table was altered, submitted a job via `dbms_job` that called the procedure to recreate the trigger.  That works but it's a rather large number of moving parts which means that it can fail in all sorts of subtle and spectacular ways particularly if the application that is making schema changes on the fly decides to add columns in the middle of the day.

Comment: Luckily we have a metadata table that we can add a trigger to to watch for changes in the other table's schema.